# Finding greatest region of match in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

A.txt contains lines that look like this (or that is, a small portion of it):

```
Green- Blue- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 1
Green- Blue- 1
```

Essentially, the last string is either a 1 or a 3. Supposing the above sample goes on for a very long time, what I need to do is find the greatest amount of consecutive lines that have 1 at the end while keeping the number of 3s less than or equal to some number (say, 2). For example, suppose A.txt, in its entirety, looks like this:

```
Green- Blue- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 3
Green- Blue- 1
Green- Purple- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 1
Blue- Blue- 3
```

Then the script would write to another text file the following lines:

```
Green- Blue- 1
Green- Purple- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 1
```

How would I code this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"All I can think of is extremely inefficient methods using count."_ - Well please add that attempt to question. You'll be more likely to receive help if you show you made an effort to solve your problem. Also, I recommend removing the module recommendation question from your main question since recommendation questions are off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really have no other choice that to iterate over the whole file, keeping track of the biggest sequence. Here is my take, encapsulated with a function: it uses a stack and iterates over the file line by line, so it should be memory efficient for large input files.

```
def foo(in_file, out_file, max_count):
    biggest, stack = [], []
    count = 0
    with open(in_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line[-2] == '3':
                count += 1
            if count > max_count:
                if len(stack) > len(biggest):
                    biggest = list(stack)
                # this line trims the list after the first element that ends with '3'
                stack = stack[stack.index(next(x for x in stack if x[-2] == '3')) + 1:]
                count = max_count
            stack.append(line)

    with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(max(biggest, stack)))
```

**Note**: This will work as intended only if the file contains a blank line at the end, and assumes that `max_count` will always be greater than 0 (otherwise the call to `next` throws an Exception that is not handled).

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the starting string is completely irrelevant.  Secondly, there's probably 100 ways to solve this problem.  I'm just gonna list the one I seem to like the best

We can also assume that the starting boundary will always be:

a) The start of the list

b) Right after a 3

We can also assume that the ending boundary will always be:

a) The end of the list

b) Right before a 3

So, lets make a new

```
threes = [-1, ... numbers.length + 1]
```

where the ... is the line numbers of every 3. I add -1 and numbers.length + 1 to the list in order to "pretend" that our list is surrounded by two 3's, in order to simplify the logic.

Since it's not specified in the problem statement, we can also assume that the list will always contain at least 2 3s, if that is possible.  The reason is, that would give us the greatest range.

Now, all we need to do is find the greatest range of line numbers between any two threes.

```
max_range = -1 # number of lines between two 3s.
max_start = -1 # start line
max_end = -1   # end line

if len(threes) == 2: # special case here.  If the original list contains no 3s, we will take the whole list.
    max_start = threes[0]
    max_end = threes[1]
    max_range = max_end - max_start
else:
    for i in range(len(threes) - 2):
        # The general case.  Find the range between any two consecutive 3s.
        start = threes[i]
        end = threes[i + 2]
        range = end - start

        if range > max_range:
            max_start = start
            max_end = end
            max_range = range
max_start += 1
max_end -= 1
max_range -= 2
```

There's a few edge cases to work out here, but this should get you started.

The first edge case (not really defined in the problem) is what happens if I end up with [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]?  Should I take 0-3, 0-4, or 0-5?  All seem to be valid solutions.  In this code, I take 0-5 because it was not specified, and it makes the code simpler.

Comment: I was more giving pseudo code, rather than a language specific answer.  But, that's fair enough.

Comment: It is pythonified

Answer (score 1):

Something you can look at storing the indices with the combination of itertools.groupby

```
txt = '''Green- Blue- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 3
Green- Blue- 1
Green- Purple- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 1
Blue- Blue- 3'''

import operator
from itertools import groupby
str_lst = list( enumerate( txt.split('\n') ) )

grp_lst = [ list(g) for k, g in groupby( [ (k,v[-1]) for k, v in str_lst ], key=operator.itemgetter(1) ) ]
filter_lst  = [ (i[0], len(i)) for i in grp_list if i[0][1] == '1' ]

for i in grp_list:
    if i[0] == max( dict(filter_lst).items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1) )[0]:
        idx = grp_list.index(i)
        break

for i in sum( grp_lst[idx:idx+3], [] ):
    print (str_lst[i[0]][1])
```

Output:

```
Green- Blue- 1
Green- Purple- 1
Red- Black- 3
Brown- Blue- 3
Black- Red- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.

First, read the file and extract only the data you actually need, i.e. the last digit.

```
x = ''
for i, line in enumerate(txt.split('\n')):
    try:
        x += line[-1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

You end up with a string containing all the 1s and 3s as they appear line after line.

```
>>>print x
'1333113313'
```

At this point, you can iterate over this string and collect all the possible substring that do not contain 3s more than twice. You can keep track of the index of the first letter of the string as well as its length.

```
results = {}
for i, n in enumerate(x):
    for idx in range(i+1, len(x)):
        if x[i:idx].count('3') <= 2:
            results[i] = len(x[i:idx])
        else:
            break
```

Finally, sort the results based on the length, and you end up with the line number at which you longest sequence starts and for how many lines it last.

```
m = sorted(results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[-1]
>>>print m
(4, 5)
```

You can use this info to write the output file. So you will save 5 lines starting from line 4.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as inp, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in inp.readlines()[m[0]:m[0]+m[1]]
        out.write(line)
```